# Can l use feline fresh litter for my shrubs?

Tags: shrubs

Its call 100% yellow southern pine pellets and I'm having an issue getting information if this would be OK to put under my shrubs these are mature shrubs and l am putting food spikes in as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used, or not? Unused by cats, it's essentially the same thing as pellet fuel (which is usually cheaper per ton) and that is compressed sawdust - with water exposure it becomes just sawdust.

You can put it under your shrubs as mulch, but it is a very carbon-rich material (something like 400:1 C:N ratio) so it may have some effect on the available nutrients (less so if not mixed in to the soil) as it will be taking up nitrogen for a considerable time in order to finally break down.

Used by cats first it has more nitrogen, but also more pathogens and smelly bits that contra-indicate spreading it on the surface of the ground or using it in the garden at all, per most advice.

Comment: It would be unused so I'm hoping the spikes will add the nutrients? Or is it a waste of time? What would be better?

Comment: Sawdust can be a valid much, but you might want to also use things like grass clippings that are more nitrogen rich, and also make a good mulch (if not put on too thick). And don't go overboard on the thickness. Large quantities of sawdust tend to be rather sterile, which I guess works if you're going for "no weeds" (or anything else) but goes less well with plants. To the extent that fertilizer spikes work, having them under the mulch should help. I'm more in favor of a layer of actual compost so I don't really have much experience with combining chemicals and mulch.